# Science fiction game involving a family of aliens on a trip who are separated by an evil guy in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, aliens, video-games

I remember being obsessed with this game from 2017-2019. It was a puzzle game that I played in school but I don't think I was allowed to, and it was supposed to be for kids but it was actually really advanced. I can't remember the name. If you know the game "Wheely" it was similar to that game style, with the puzzles, plot and levels.

The plot was that there was a family of aliens on a trip but they were separated by this evil guy on a spaceship. The little brother escapes and he's trying to solve the puzzles to save his family. Anyone know what this game was called?